# How can I use character styles in my table?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, character-styles, character

[character styles only visible[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyQmX.jpg) when just type in one cell highlighted][2cell styles panel only[[image: ]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5cAj.jpg)I would like to highlight an entire column or row and apply a Character style to that row or column but I cannot. I tried cell styles and cannot get font attributes to be applied? I think I know so much and realize I hardly know anything about indesign yet work in it everyday.
Example first COLUMN I have a different color and style font from all other columns except for one.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. you highlight the column/row and apply the style just like you would a text frame.

Comment: You are right, haste makes waste, I apologize. I am working in INDesign CC and have different fonts and font color in one column and the rest of the columns. I am changing the color and although the font change is a NEW character style, when I highlight the whole column to be changed the character style is grayed out, so I am only able to highlight each cell in order to apply the character style to that font. This is very tedious, needless to say.

Comment: Still not seeing an issue, here. I can highlight a column and apply a character style across teh entire thing in one click. Any chance you need to override a cell style or something?

Comment: I can highlight an entire column and change the color by going to the color palette and then keep the highlighted column and go to the Font and change the font but I am looking to do this by highlighting and then clicking ONCE onto the character style but the character styles do not show up in the character styles box, only cell styles are in that box. Cell styles are accessible but not character styles. Can i add pictures in this query?

Comment: Well, cell styles appear in the **Cell Styles Panel**.. character styles appear in the **Character Styles Panel**.. it's two *different* panels. If you are seeing Cell Styles, you're *looking at the wrong panel*. And yes you can ad images to the question, just click the EDIT link below it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I thought I added TWO photos but only one is showing currently. The character style window only appears if I highlight type in one cell. If I highlight the entire cell OR several cells (a column) it changes to the CELL style window. The picture shows the character style window.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS is your text. It reads.like yelling and is considered rude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are expecting the **Control Bar** to show both cell and character styles. It **doesn't** if you are working on a table. If working on a *table* the control bar shows cell and table styles rather than paragraph and character styles.

You need to *actually open* the Character Styles Panel via `Window > Styles > Character Styles`.

From the **Character Styles Panel** you can assign the character style to the entire column. You merely *can't* assign character styles via the control bar if you are working on a table. The Control Bar is meant to be a *shortcut* to *commonly* used options and not a path to each and every option possible.

Comment: YAY!!!!! Silly me, expecting a shortcut in a control bar!! Thank you! Now I how do I rate you or push your answer to the top? I hope this helps others with the same silliness!

Comment: @Amych: by voting, but you need to get a minimum of 15 reputation first (by asking good questions or answering others). From the [Help]: "Awarded At: 15 Reputation" ([Help Center > Privileges > Vote Up](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up))

Comment: Thank you so much, I will do my part! This is great, my project is so much easier today!